# Recursive delete of files and directories in C#

Tags: c#

How to delete a given directory recursively in C# ?  A directory containing files.

Should the [System.IO.Directory.Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.delete) with the second parameter `true` do the trick?

---

EDIT:

So, I actually did answer my own question, although the answers here were a little more clarifying. The reason for me asking this in the first place was that the code that has exactly that invocation of `Delete` (2nd param set to `true`) was not doing what it was supposed to be doing. As it turned out the cause of that was that there was a file somewhere down in the the directory hierarchy with `RO` attribute set, and the *Polish* version of `Windows XP` was throwing a really strange message for that.

Comment: I think you already gave the answer yourself :-)

Comment: This does seem an odd question.

The asker already knows about the second parameter, which is a boolean called "recursive".

You're basically saying "how do I do recursive? Do I set recursive to true?"

Comment: OK, perhaps the edit clarifies. The dir contains some files...

Comment: I can definitely say that this method is flaky at best. I having this exact problem where I am trying to do a recursive delete on a UNC path and even though I make sure that ALL files (not directories) are deleted before hand - this method is failing. I know for a fact those folders are empty because I created them two seconds prior. No read only files situation here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yup, that's the point of that parameter. Did you try it and have any problems? (I've just double-checked, and it works fine for me.)

Comment: Although its worth making sure there are no Read-Only files/directories in your path first.  That caused me a few problems a while back.

Comment: that is exactly the thing. THanks for the clue :D

Comment: Didn't worked for me, if the subdirectories also contains files.

Comment: @Jone: So what happened? It may be worth asking a new question.

Answer (score 35):

The only solution that worked for me if the subdirectories also contains files is by using a recursive function:

```
    public static void RecursiveDelete(DirectoryInfo baseDir)
    {
        if (!baseDir.Exists)
            return;

        foreach (var dir in baseDir.EnumerateDirectories())
        {
            RecursiveDelete(dir);
        }
        baseDir.Delete(true);
    }
```

It appears that Directory.Delete(dir, true) only delete files of the current directory, and subdirectories if they are empty.

Hope it helps someone.

btw, example:  `RecursiveDelete( new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\my_dir") );`

Comment: Interesting enough, this doesn't work for me, since the "baseDir.Delete" tries to Delete folder which aren't arround anymore.

Answer (score 12):

If you get UnauthorizedAccessException .
You can use modified of **RecursiveDelete** from **[Jone Polvora](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22282428/3195477)**. Thank you for Idea. I will use it.

```
    public static void RecursiveDelete(DirectoryInfo baseDir)
    {
        if (!baseDir.Exists)
            return;

        foreach (var dir in baseDir.EnumerateDirectories())
        {
            RecursiveDelete(dir);
        }
        var files = baseDir.GetFiles();
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            file.IsReadOnly = false;
            file.Delete();
        }
        baseDir.Delete();
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Recursive works for both files and folders (oddly, I thought it didn't work for files; my bad...):

```
// create some nested folders...
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\foo");
Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\foo\bar");
// ...with files...
File.WriteAllText(@"c:\foo\blap.txt", "blup");
File.WriteAllText(@"c:\foo\bar\blip.txt", "blop");
// ...and delete them
Directory.Delete(@"c:\foo", true); // fine
```

Comment: I don't understand - what's the need for the 2nd parameter?  Surely `Directory.Delete(@"C:\foo")` deletes `foo` and everything in it - how can you delete a directory without deleting everything in it?

Comment: @MattArnold think of it as more of a "I expect it to be empty, so if it isn't: that's a problem, please fail" vs "burn it with fire, regardless"

Answer (score 1):

Modified solution from @StayOnTarget, so that root dir is not getting removed:

```
public static void RecursiveDelete(DirectoryInfo baseDir, bool isRootDir)
{
    if (!baseDir.Exists)
        return;
    foreach (var dir in baseDir.EnumerateDirectories()) RecursiveDelete(dir, false);
    foreach (var file in baseDir.GetFiles())
    {
        file.IsReadOnly = false;
        file.Delete();
    }
    if (!isRootDir) baseDir.Delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do not use?

Directory.Delete(directoryPath, true);

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That is what he's using, isn't that what he mentions in the first line of the question?