# Recursive Deletion of Folders in C#

Tags: c#, .net, recursion, c#-6.0

I am trying to recursively delete all empty subdirectories in a root directory and (not files)using C#. I have referred this post ([Recursive delete of files and directories in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925192/recursive-delete-of-files-and-directories-in-c-sharp))
and wrote the function as follows.

```
private void DeleteEmptySubFolders()
        {
            DirectoryInfo root = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
            RecursiveDelete(root,true);
           
        }
        public static void RecursiveDelete(DirectoryInfo baseDir,bool isRootDir)
        {
            if (!baseDir.Exists)
                return;

            foreach (var dir in baseDir.EnumerateDirectories())
            {
                RecursiveDelete(dir,false);
            }
            try
            {
                if (!isRootDir)
                    baseDir.Delete(false);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                
            }
        }
```

My question is `baseDir.Delete(false);` will give me an exception when a directory is not empty, and I am just passing that exception without handling it(I just want to skip those ones, don't have to log). Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811509/c-sharp-remove-all-empty-subdirectories

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Remove all empty subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811509/c-sharp-remove-all-empty-subdirectories)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `try`/`catch`, check if any files exist:

```
bool isEmpty = !Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(baseDir.FullName).Any();
```

Now you can avoid trying to delete non-empty folders:

```
if (!isRootDir && isEmpty)
    baseDir.Delete(false);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  Since my baseDir is of type DirectoryInfo `bool isEmpty = !Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(baseDir.FullName).Any();` works. Can you please edit the answer?