# Unable to clear App cache in Xamarin.Forms Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to clear/delete app cache folder of my Xamarin.Forms Android app. I have tried different approaches, but the folder still is not getting cleared.

What I have done:

I am calling this class through an interface. But no matter what I do, the cache folder keeps having data in it.

```cs
namespace MyApp.Droid.Services
{
    public class CacheClearService: ICacheClearService
    {
        public async Task ClearCacheAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var cacheDir = Android.App.Application.Context.CacheDir;
                deleteDir(cacheDir);
                await Task.CompletedTask;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

        public  static bool deleteDir(File dir)
        {
            if (dir != null && dir.IsDirectory)
            {
                string[] children = dir.List();
                for (int i = 0; i < children.Length; i++)
                {
                    bool success= deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                    if (!success)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return dir.Delete();
            }
            else if (dir != null && dir.IsFile)
            {
                return dir.Delete();
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I have added permissions like `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.
What am I missing here? Any help is appreciated

Comment: Those permissions are irrelevant for your app-specific directory. You can always read and write that folder. Is this Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.Forms **or** MAUI? Why do you have an asynchronous method that doesn't do anything asynchronously?

Comment: @Julian This is Xamarin.forms app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues and things to consider here.

## 1. Permissions

First of all, you don't need the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions to read and write your app's private cache and app data folders.

## 2. Use file system helpers

To obtain the path of your app's cache directory, you could simply use the [file system helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/essentials/file-system-helpers?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android#using-file-system-helpers) of the *Xamarin.Essentials* package/namespace:

```cs
using Xamarin.Essentials;

namespace MyApp.Droid.Services
{
    public class CacheClearService : ICacheClearService
    {
        public async Task ClearCacheAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                var cacheDir = FileSystem.CacheDirectory;

                // skipped for brevity
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }

        // skipped for brevity
    }
}
```

## 3. Simplify deletion code

Your deletion code can be simplified. You can use the [Directory.Delete(string path, bool recursive)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.delete?view=netstandard-2.0#system-io-directory-delete(system-string-system-boolean)) method instead by passing the path and `true` as the second argument to delete files and subfolders similar to how it's done in [Recursive delete of files and directories in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925192/recursive-delete-of-files-and-directories-in-c-sharp):

```cs
private static void DeleteDir(string dir)
{
    foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
    {
        DeleteDir(subDir);
    }
    Directory.Delete(dir, true);
}
```

## 4. async/await

Last but not least, your interface seems to require you to implement the method that clears the cache as an awaitable Task. However, in your implementation, you don't perform any asynchronous calls except for awaing the `Task.CompletedTask`, which returns immediately, because it's always in its completed state.

Instead, you could wrap your *blocking* code *(deleting files and folders may take a while)* in a `Task.Run()` statement, which can then be awaited:

```cs
public async Task ClearCacheAsync()
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var cacheDir = FileSystem.CacheDirectory;
            DeleteDir(cacheDir);
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //maybe log the exception here?
    }
}
```

## 5. Bringing it all together

```cs
namespace MyApp.Droid.Services
{
    public class CacheClearService : ICacheClearService
    {
        public async Task ClearCacheAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    var cacheDir = FileSystem.CacheDirectory;
                    DeleteDir(cacheDir);
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //maybe log the exception here?
            }
        }

        private static void DeleteDir(string dir)
        {
            foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
            {
                DeleteDir(subDir);
            }
            Directory.Delete(dir, true);
        }
    }
}
```

***Note:** This should work on both Android and iOS.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me try this

Comment: I tried your code and the cache data is still there. The code executed without exception

Comment: That's strange, it works for me. I've tried out this code in a fresh Xamarin.Forms app. Are you sure you're accessing the right folder? Are there some files that might be in use?

Comment: your code works. But what I found was my cache folder is in external Directory. So how to access that path?Since Filesystem.Cachedirectory returns only internal storge path I guess

Comment: for external CacheDirectory I accessed like this. var cacheDir = Android.App.Application.Context.ExternalCacheDir; Thanks for the answer . +1

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. Yes, it depends on which folder you use. Typically, the internal one would be used, unless you want to share data with other apps.